# How can i override the mail activity js file?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I want to override the class Activity in activity js file (mail module):

```
odoo.define('mail/static/src/models/activity/activity/js', function (require) {
'use strict';

const { registerNewModel } = require('mail/static/src/model/model_core.js');
const { attr, many2many, many2one } = require('mail/static/src/model/model_field.js');
const { clear } = require('mail/static/src/model/model_field_command.js');

function factory(dependencies) {

    class Activity extends dependencies['mail.model'] {
        ............
```

Thanks for advice.

Comment: You got the solution? if yes, please share

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `registerInstancePatchModel` function.

At the bottom of activity.js, you will see:

```js
registerNewModel('mail.activity', factory);
```

Then in your js file, if you wanted to override the `_computeNote` function:

```js
import { registerInstancePatchModel } from '@mail/model/model_core';

registerInstancePatchModel('mail.activity', 'your_module_name', {
    _computeNote() {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments); // if you want to call super

        // your code...
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as @ConorLe has mentioned that is the best way to override and patch mail activity functions. To help you understand better you can see an example of an OCA module [mail_tracking](https://github.com/OCA/social/blob/14.0/mail_tracking) using it [here](https://github.com/OCA/social/blob/b827e0ad38624c664934e5188817586b7e3aa013/mail_tracking/static/src/js/discuss/discuss.js#L108) for Odoo 14.0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).